# Beta progress indicator "2.5 answers per question"

Tags: discussion, beta

In DevOps, for sure more than one solution approach can be possible to a given problem, however while questions are required to be very narrow and not allowing opinions, this creates in my understanding room for more focused answers which then can't be many, maybe just two.

Why is it good, and how possible to have more than two answers to so precise questions?

Comment: There can be multiple ways of getting something done. Sometimes, work-arounds. So, they'd also be considered as helpful responses